# Gradient not showing in Custom Android View

Tags: android, view, gradient

I'm creating my own view. Right now all I want to do is draw a rounded rect with a color gradient.

Here is how I create the gradient:

```
public void changePressedColor(int[] colors){
    if (colors != null){
        if (colors.length == 2){
            pressedcolors = colors;
            whenpressed = new LinearGradient(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),pressedcolors[0],pressedcolors[1], Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Wherre pressed colors are passed as a parameter from:

```
    int[] pc = new int[2];
    pc[0] = Color.rgb(0,0,50);
    pc[1] = Color.rgb(114,112,255);
```

Then when I draw I do this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    painter.setShader(whenpressed);
    painter.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect,rx,ry,painter);

    painter.setShader(null);
    painter.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    painter.setColor(textColor);
    canvas.drawText(text,cx,cy+offsety,painter);
}
```

The problem is that no gradient appears. Instead there is a solid color equal to first color of the gradient. The height of the view, rect and therefore the gradient is the same.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when you call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, they may not have been calculated yet.

Comment: Nice try! But, unfortunately no. Its value is 48, same as the button height.

Comment: And you're checking it's correct inside `changePressedColor`, not in `onDraw`?

Comment: Whoa!!! You were right!!! This was the problem, I got the height from an Internal variable and it worked. I just didn't see it because I had other code problems. Thank you!